# How to modify Python str object to produce a provenance report noting all files that modify a string

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to figure out how to modify or replace ALL instances of the base string type str in a Python 3 program. What I want to do is add provenance to the string. The idea being that anytime a string is created it notes what source file created the string. From there any time a string is assigned I'd like the prior string's history to follow the string.

```
import sys
import inspect
import builtins

class ProvenanceString(str):

    def __new__(cls, string, source=None):
        return super().__new__(cls, string)

    def __init__(self, value=None, source=None):
        super().__init__()
        self._myinit(value, source)

    def _myinit(self, value, source):
        self.history = []
        self.sources = []
        if hasattr(value, 'history'):
            self.history = value.history
        callerframerecord = inspect.stack()[2]
        frame = callerframerecord[0]
        info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
        self.history.append("{}:{}".format(info.filename, info.lineno))
        if hasattr(value, 'sources'):
            self.sources = value.sources
        if source:
            self.sources.append(source)
        return


    def get_history(self):
        return self.history

    def get_sources(self):
        return self.sources

#builtins.str = ProvenanceString # doesn't work

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mystr = "This is my string"
    print (type(mystr))
    #print(mystr.get_history()) # doesn't work
    #print(mystr.get_sources()) # doesn't work
    myobjstr = ProvenanceString("my prov string", "src1")
    print (type(myobjstr))

    print(myobjstr.get_history())
    print(myobjstr.get_sources())

    myobjstr2 = ProvenanceString(myobjstr, "src2")
    print(myobjstr2.get_history())
    print(myobjstr2.get_sources())
    sys.exit(0)
```

Results:

```
<class 'str'>
<class '__main__.ProvenanceString'>
['./provenance.py:44']
['src1']
['./provenance.py:44', './provenance.py:50']
['src1', 'src2']
```

So how do I get ProvenanceString to replace all instances of the base str so that I can trace where strings are being generated and how they flow through the system. Potentially I might even want to report on how those strings changed throughout the system as well.

Comment: 98% sure this is impossible in ordinary Python. You'd have to write your own interpreter with special extended string functionality.

Comment: Well not entirely, this is a relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835469/extending-pythons-builtin-str